# Don't nofollow links in posts if the poster has enough rep

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, nofollow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove nofollow on links at a certain age](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age)

This is related to [Remove nofollow on links at a certain age](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age). Can we assume that when users reach a certain reputation they're probably including links in posts because they're actually a good reference (as opposed to just spamming something) and start dropping the nofollow attribute on them? I always assumed this happened, until I tried to find out what the rep limit was and realize we just nofollow everything all the time. There could be restrictions if the poster has posted the same site a bunch of times, if necessary

<sub>(Inspired by [this article](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/104/stackoverflow-amongst-nofollow-web-abuse-sites))</sub>

Comment: Agree, but to clear up the misnomer: Google does indeed follow "nofollow" links. It was introduced charmingly to have blog owners do some free linkspam cleanup labour for Google. It's presence indicates active moderation work and vetted links. It's therefore silly to assume that nofollow links don't contribute *any* pagerank whatsoever nowadays.

Comment: [This was asked before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age) but declined. I agree, though. Like Robert said, "Stack Overflow is about making the Internet a better place and giving back."

Comment: I read somewhere (the blog?) that the nofollow was removed at 2K rep.

Comment: @John: That's [only the link to your website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age/69032#69032) on your profile.

Comment: @Borror0: Oh, wow.  That's worse than I thought.

Comment: @Borror That was based on post age, not poster rep; I linked to that same post in my question

Comment: Having just spent a few minutes perusing [this list](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/95107/shin-kickees), I'm even less enthusiastic about this idea than I was when the previous suggestion was posted. *goes back to fetal position, fully clothed in the shower*