# How to put rel="nofollow" link?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

How to make a convenient (clickable) link but one which does not advertise the target to search engines?

[link example](http://example.com/)

Comment: I thought all links were automagically nofollow, so what's the problem?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @Ivo, For example, [the link to "is.gd"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) on meta comment is not rel="nofollow", so that "all links are automatically nofollow" does not hold.

Comment: @Bobby, It should be useful when discussing malware/spam. /* Poor man's nofollow is like "hxxp://spam.example.com/malware.exe", but there should be a better mode */

Comment: [Sorry for not being clearer:](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age/69032#69032) "Our policy is the same as Wikipedia's. You get a followed link in the "website" field of your user profile at 2000 reputation. Beyond that, **everything outside the network is nofollowed as a simple matter of standard policy.** Exactly like, and for all the same reasons as, Wikipedia."

Comment: @Vi: In that case there should never be a click- or easily followable link, it should always be garbled to protect the innocent. *With garbled I mean it should not be able to be turned into a link automatically, like with Linkify (FF Addon). Humans should be able to revert the changes to retrieve it.*

Comment: [example link 2](http://example.com/)

Comment: I get the impression you guys are talking about different things. My understanding of teh question is rel="nofollow" my understanding of the above comments is munged links.

Comment: @Wes: No, Ivo and Vi are still talking about the same thing, I am talking about what to do with links which are linking against possible malicious content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Links are automatically nofollow, but not in preview (which confused me at first).

Comment: Automatic addition of rel=nofollow is depends on your reps, imho (but preview is not, that's correct, since google can't crawl your preview)

Comment: @you we don't allow following links anywhere except on the user profile URL field, if you have 2k+ rep

Comment: Ahh, @Jeff, I was trying with http://stackoverflow.com, which was inside link, thats why then.