# Puppin.org seems to be scraping SO content

Tags: discussion, content-reuse

news.puppin.org seems to be scraping right into a wordpress blog, and ranking in searches too. I ran across this link:

```
http://news.puppin.org/question/non-relational-db-which-one-is-the-right-choice-closed/
```

Comment: Just FYI, long-standing MSO policy is not to link to any suspected scrapers.

Comment: @waiwai: All links are `no-follow`, right? So why would it matter?

Comment: @Gabe No idea, but MSO has never been about proper logic and reason. :)

Comment: Also, you might want to report this at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962

Comment: @Paul — as @waiwai said, please add this to the list at [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962). That'll help get them shut down, as they aren't even attempting to pretend to try to meet the attribution requirements.

Comment: @Gabe: The no-follow is removed for old links.

Comment: Added this site to the other list. Don't suppose there's a lot else I can do at this point.

Comment: @Tim: Do you have a citation for that? I thought they tried removing `no-follow` temporarily and then stopped.

Comment: @Gabe I'm also interested in whatever the final solution has become. It's unfortunate if such a valuable archive of content doesn't end up contributing outward back to the internet.

Comment: @Gabe: You seem to be right, I didn't know that.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age