# Do edits affect rel=nofollow addition?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, hyperlinks

I answered a question here: [Parsing HTML to fix microtypography & glyph issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700054/parsing-html-to-fix-microtypography-glyph-issues/13751428#13751428) and remember remarking to my "somewhat-friend" that I was happy because the links didn't contain rel=nofollow. He's done some good work, the links are relevant, and I think he deserves the the search engine juice, I was ecstatic that the SO algs. agreed.

Recently my post was edited to be in a form that the editor found more attractive. Now the links are all tagged rel=nofollow.

My questions are:

- Does editing a post reset or affect the decision to apply rel=nofollow to outgoing links
- Even if the links are all to the same place as they were pre-edit?
- Can I revert the edit to get the original state back
- (or was I just mis-reading code a while back and they've always been tagged)

Comment: Please don't revert it. The post looks much better as edited - inline links with no text descriptions look horrible. You can't even guarantee that a rollback will remove the nofollow links, as a rollback actually creates a new revision.

Comment: Related [Remove nofollow on links deemed reputable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111279/145673)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can't give out specific details of how nofollow removal works due to exploitation, I can say that an edit does push links in a post back in to nofollow territory.  After a bit of time and community vetting nofollow will be removed again.

Comment: As a followup, it's been almost two months since the post was edited (not changing link destinations at all) by someone with more karma than me (he's at 9k+ now) and the links are **still** _rel=nofollow_. I think this does a disservice to the internet at large.