# Remove 'nofollow' for Community Ads

Tags: feature-request, nofollow

It's [already the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable) that links deemed 'reputable' don't have `nofollow` (though the exact details are deliberately vague, and even the links in this [heavily upvoted post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19509/1396) by our top user on dba.se don't qualify).

My suggestion is that links to sites already deemed reputable by another means — voting on [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) proposals — are automatically also deemed reputable for `nofollow` purposes.

My personal interest is [the db<>fiddle ad](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2676) promoted by dba.se.